# Python pandas, how to installl/build 32bit version pandas on 64bit windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows, visual-c++, build

When I try to install the pandas with python 3.12.2/32BIT,
it tell me error as below. I have installed 32bit MSVC on the system.
What should I do to build and go the pandas when I use pip?
(I have zero experience to build packages)

---

(error log start)

Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
?─> [23 lines of output]
+ meson setup C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gl88rctd\pandas_33975656788c41e593cabf5374dfa29e C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gl88rctd\pandas_33975656788c41e593cabf5374dfa29e.mesonpy-z2kyp0wn\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gl88rctd\pandas_33975656788c41e593cabf5374dfa29e.mesonpy-z2kyp0wn\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.1
Source dir: C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gl88rctd\pandas_33975656788c41e593cabf5374dfa29e
Build dir: C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gl88rctd\pandas_33975656788c41e593cabf5374dfa29e.mesonpy-z2kyp0wn\build
Build type: native build
Project name: pandas
Project version: 2.2.0
Activating VS 17.8.6
C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.38.33135 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ ????? ??????? ??? 19.38.33135(x64)")
C linker for the host machine: link link 14.38.33135.0
C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.38.33135 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ ????? ??????? ??? 19.38.33135(x64)")
C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.38.33135.0
Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 3.0.5)
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program python found: YES (C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312-32\python.exe)
Need python for x86_64, but found x86
Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried sysconfig)

```
  ..\..\pandas\_libs\tslibs\meson.build:32:7: ERROR: Python dependency not found

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gl88rctd\pandas_33975656788c41e593cabf5374dfa29e\.mesonpy-z2kyp0wn\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
?─> See above for output.

Comment: Do you have 32 or 64 bit python running?

Comment: @Hermann12  32BIT python on Win 11 64 bits. And I also have installed MSVC 32bit and MSVC 64bit both.